# Why doesn't uploadify work for me in Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, uploadify

I am trying to do a simple file upload from my ASP.NET MVC web app using uploadify.  In IE8, it works fine.  In Firefox and Chrome, it never seems to post to the controller action.  Can someone help me find what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my html:

```
<input type="file" id="file_upload" name="FileData" />
```

I am including jquery 1.4.1 and the contents of the current version of uploadify 2.1.4, which itself includes swfobject 2.2.

Here's my script:

$(function () {

```
$("#file_upload").uploadify({
  'uploader':   '/Scripts/uploadify.swf',
  'script':     '/Uploads/UploadFile',
  'cancelImg':  '/Content/Images/cancel.png',
  'auto':       true,
  'multi':      false,
  'folder':     '/uploads',

  onComplete : function() {
    alert("complete");
  },

  onOpen : function() {
    alert("open");
  },

  onError : function (event, id, fileObj, errorObj) {
    alert("error: " + errorObj.info);
  }

});
```

});

And here's my controller action:

```
public string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase FileData)
{
    // do stuff with the file
}
```

In Chrome and Firefox, I get a  "Error #2038" message, which seems pretty cryptic from what I can find on the google.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When and where do you get the error message?

Comment: The error message is just in the errorObj in the onError callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to try:

1. Your controller action should return ActionResult, not string
2. Install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and see what happens under the covers (you will see the HTTP request/response frames and a possible error). Then compare the results between the different browsers to see if something changes.

Comment: Thanks... I had tried to use fiddler earlier to see this, but I never noticed the post back to the controller.  After I read up on how to get fiddler to log localhost requests, it became clear that this was an authentication thing, since the ASP.NET session is different in the flash request than it is in my standard browser-based requests.  Thanks!

Comment: How did you fix this? I have the same problem, my code works with IE but not with Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: Can you please post the solution on how you fixed this.. will be really useful to all who are having similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Like Chris Farmer said, session is different in the flash request, cookies .ASPXAUTH (or other session cookie) aren't sent in Chrome and Firefox (You can watch this with Fiddler2)

To solve this problem, you can use "scriptData" with uploadify. This is how i proceed :

Add this to your uploadify js :

```
string scriptDataValues = string.Empty;
            if (Request.Cookies != null && Request.Cookies.Length > 0)
            {
                //  Generate scriptData
                scriptDataValues = ", 'scriptData' : {";
                string[] formatedData = new string[Request.Cookies.Length];
                int i = 0;
                foreach (HttpCookie cookie in cookies)
                {
                    // Format cookie to scriptData name:value
                    formatedData[i] = string.Format("\"{0}\":\"{1}\"", cookie.Name, cookie.Value);
                    i++;
                }
                // separate all formated cookies with comma
                scriptDataValues += string.Join(",", formatedData);
                scriptDataValues += "}";
            }
     // add scriptData to your js script
    string yourScript = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
$(document).ready(function () { $('#file_upload').uploadify({
      'uploader'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
      'script'      : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
      'cancelImg'   : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
      'folder'      : '/uploads'
      " + scriptDataValues + "
    }); }); 
</script>"
```

And in your action in your controller :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadProductImage(HttpPostedFileBase image, FormCollection collec)
        {
            Partner partner = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(collec[".ASPXAUTH"]))
            {
                // Get cookie in POST values
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(collec[".ASPXAUTH"]);
                if (ticket.Expiration > DateTime.Now)
                {
                     // Authenticated user, upload the file and return url
                }
             }
        return this.Content(string.Empty);
        }
```